# Edit/Update user informations after loggin [Android]

Tags: java, php, android

I am currently working on an Android app who can manage user informations. For that I have a Register form (name, username, email and password) and after Logging, my app display a toast ('Welcome "username"'). And now i am having some issues... I don't know how to make an activity where the user can update his informations like his mail adress, his username or his password.

Code of my LoginActivity.java

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

public ImageView bgLogo;

Button login_button;
EditText Username, Password;
String username, password;
String login_url = "http://192.168.0.19/login.php";
AlertDialog.Builder builder;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); // Enlever la barre bleue
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    initExit ();

    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
    login_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogin);
    Username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);

    login_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            username = Username.getText().toString();
            password = Password.getText().toString();

            if (username.equals("") || password.equals("")) {

                builder.setTitle("Mince une erreur...");
                displayAlert("Veuillez entrer un username et un mot de passe correct...");
            }

            else {

                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, login_url,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {

                                JSONArray jsonArray = null;
                                try {
                                    jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                                    String code = jsonObject.getString("code");

                                    if (code.equals("login_failed")) {

                                        builder.setTitle("Erreur d'authentification");
                                        displayAlert(jsonObject.getString("message"));
                                    }

                                    else {

                                        Intent intent = new Intent (getBaseContext(), UserAreaActivity.class);
                                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                        bundle.putString("name", jsonObject.getString("name"));
                                        intent.putExtras(bundle);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                    }
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Erreur", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        error.printStackTrace();

                    }
                })
                {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                        Map <String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        params.put("user_name", username);
                        params.put("password", password);
                        return params;
                    }
                };

                MySingleton.getInstance(LoginActivity.this).addToRequestque(stringRequest);
            }
        }
    });
}

private void initExit() {

    bgLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bgLogo1);
    bgLogo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick (View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent (LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

public void displayAlert (String message) {

    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Username.setText("");
            Password.setText("");
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // do nothing.
    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    return;
}
```

Code of my UserAreaActivity.java

```
public class UserAreaActivity extends Activity {

public ImageView bgNet;
public ImageView bgChat;
public ImageView bgStats;
public ImageView bgGo;
public Button bLogout;

TextView name;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); // Enlever la barre bleue
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_area);

    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null)
    {
        name.setText(" "+bundle.getString("name"));
    }

    else
    {
        name.setText("Ajanthan");
    }

    initGoHome ();
    initPlay ();
    initGoStats ();
    initGoChat ();
    buttonLogout ();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    return;
}

private void initGoHome () {

    bgNet = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bgNet);
    bgNet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick (View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent (UserAreaActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

private void initPlay () {

    bgGo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bgGo);
    bgGo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick (View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent (UserAreaActivity.this, PlayActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

private void initGoStats () {

    bgStats = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bgStats);
    bgStats.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick (View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent (UserAreaActivity.this, StatsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

private void initGoChat () {

    bgChat = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bgChat);
    bgChat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick (View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent (UserAreaActivity.this, ChatActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

private void buttonLogout () {

    bLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogout);
    bLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick (View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent (UserAreaActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

And picture of my UserAreaActivity where I want the users to update their informations.
[image: Layout of my UserAreaActivity]

Answers are always welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

In your PHP server, you need create a method which can do it.
I see you can POST to server. So Post new information for the server in JSON.
{
  user_id: 1
  email : newemail@email.em
}

http://192.168.0.19/edit_user.php
Here you need to read values from the request. Change data in database, and send back a response.

In Android, you can again reload the user's information. When edit is successful, than its work good.

Write data loading to onResume().

Don't forget to use JsonWebToken, or something for security connection!!

Load data ->Go edit screen->POST data to server->Server change values is database->Write success/fail msg on android->close edit screen->Load data again

Answer (score 0):

You can user onLongPress listener on TextView and then when user long press show a dialog to get username. When user done then update that text to server by api calling and then update your textview.